# Printing multiple files along with file names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder with unknown number of subfolders eg: say sb1 sb2 sb3 sb4... sbn
Every sub folder has a file readme.txt
I can iterate through all folders and readme.txt file inside that folder and print lines that start with 'This is how you'

I'm able to print them like this:

```
sb1: This is how you install Python
sb1: This is how you install Django
sb1: This is how you create virtual environment
sb2: This is how you upgrade your Mac
sb2: This is how you upgrade Windows operating system
sb2: This is how you blah blah blah
```

But I need to have the output like below: Basically group the output from a particular sub folder into a section ..rather than printing the subfolder name every time.

```
######## SB1 #########
This is how you install Python
This is how you install Django
This is how you create virtual environment

######## SB2 #########
This is how you upgrade your Mac
This is how you upgrade Windows operating system
This is how you blah blah blah
```

Code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd(), onerror=None):
    for filename in files:  # iterate over the files in the current dir
        if filename == 'readme.txt':
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
                for line in fp:
                    if line.startswith('This is how'):
                        result.add(os.path.relpath(file_path) + ":" + line)
```

Comment: It looks like `result` is a list. Instead, make it a dictionary where the key is the directory name and the value is a list of strings. Ex: `{"sb1": ["install Python", "install Django"], "sb2": ["upgrade your Mac", "upgrade Windows"]}`

Comment: Yeah good point.. I thought dictionary is a key : value pair .. didn't think value can be a list.. let me see how I can create a list as value and append

Comment: As an aside, you could skip iterating filenames by just doing `if "readme.txt" in filenames`. You could take it a step further. Skip that `if` too but instead try the open in a try/except block and just catch the oserror when the file does not exist. You could even skip `os.walk` and after `from glob import glob` just do `for filename in glob("**/readme.txt")

Comment: for filename in glob("**/readme.txt"):
        with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                if search_text in line.split():
                    result[filename] = [line].

Comment: With above code, im able to add the last line as value to key in dictionary.. but struggling in keeping all the lines as elements in list

Comment: eg: {'sb1/readme.txt': ['This is how you create virtual environment\n'], 'sb2/readme.txt': ['This is how you blah blah blah']}

Comment: I got it, thank you folks, you all are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing each folder contains only one readme File. Instead of saving each line in a list, i would opt to print it out directly, if you dont need the files so something along the lines of:

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd(), onerror=None):
    for filename in files:  # iterate over the files in the current dir
        if filename == 'readme.txt':
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print('########' + os.path.relpath(file_path) + '#########')
            with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
                for line in fp:
                    if line.startswith('This is how'):
                        print(line)
```

If you need the values use a dict as suggested by @Johnny Mopp

Comment: In this case, it'll print all folder names that has readme.txt file eventhough they don't have lines starting with 'This is how'... correct?

Comment: Yes. In order to print only the ones with lines starting this is how i would move it below the lower if statement and tick a flag

Comment: @PrasadY - Do you want to skip printing subfolders without "This is how"? If so, let us know - especially in the question itself.

Comment: Sure, yeah thats what I need. going with above comments, Im able to add the last line in the file as value to key..but can't keep all lines in list.